# File Uploading service gets failed from android whereas works with IOS

Tags: wcf

I had created the WCF service for file uploading. Its working fine when the service hits from web application or from IOS device. But its throwing an exception when it comes from Android device.

I tried to multiparse the streamdata. Its throwing an exception as like file unavailable.

```
public OASIS.Entity.Shared.UserFileUpload FileUpload(Stream data, string UploadMode)
    {
        OASIS.Entity.Shared.UserFileUpload userFileUpload = new Entity.Shared.UserFileUpload();
        try
        {
            MultipartParser parser = new MultipartParser(data);
            string fileName = string.Empty;
            string filePath = string.Empty;
            string allowedExtensions = string.Empty;
            int allowedFileSizeMB = 0;

            if (parser.FileAvailable)
            {
              // File Available for IOS / Web application.
              //  userFileUpload 
            }
            else
            {
              // From android device file is getting not available.
            }
         }
          catch (Exception exp)
        {
            OASIS.Utility.ExceptionManager.HandleException(exp);
            userFileUpload = null;
        }
      return userFileUpload;
     }
```

Expecting it should get work for android device too.

Answer (score 0):

By default, WCF does not support form data files, so it looks like you are using MultipartParser to convert form data (data from a file stream uploaded through a form-data).
If this class can handle data submitted in IOS, it should also be able to handle data submitted through forms in Andriod, after all, the HTTP protocol is cross-platform. 
thereby I would like to know, how do you upload data in the Andriod system?
By adding breakpoint debugging, can you use this class to parse form data properly?
I suggest you handle the form-data by creating the service with asp.net WebAPI.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2
Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.